# Use webpack-dev-server with multiple entries and HMR

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I have 3 entries in my webpack.config.js that generate 3 different HTML files.   I do this so I can host them on separate domains:

- index.html = http://app.local
- site.html = http://site.local
- forms.html = http://forms.local

Right now I have a custom dev server that launches the webpack build three times so that I can point to what the index file should be.  What I'd like to do is change this to a single server and use the host header to decide what index file to load.

The way I've tried to do this is:

```
    devServer: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        /// Enable gzip
        compress: true,
        contentBase: './dist',
        /* Theoretically, the public option is better but they only support a single host
         *
         * This is a security issue not using public.
         * */
        disableHostCheck: true,

        // enable HMR on the server
        hot: true,
        overlay: true,
        after: (app) => {
            /* Server the dev settings that are normally injected via nginx */
            app.get('/settings.js', function(req, res) {
                const fullPath = path.join(__dirname, "settings.dev.js");
                res.sendFile(fullPath);
            });

            app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
                const headers = req.headers;
                const host = headers['host'];

                if (
                    /* We only wan't to override GET */
                    (req.method !== 'GET') ||

                    /* They didn't send an accept header */
                    (!headers || typeof headers.accept !== 'string') ||

                    /* They prefer JSON */
                    (headers.accept.indexOf('application/json') === 0) ||

                    /* They don't want HTML */
                    (!acceptsHtml(headers.accept))
                ) {
                    console.log("TERMINATING EARLY", req.method, headers.accept);
                    return next();
                }

                let indexFile = 'index.html';

                switch(host) {
                    case "site":
                        indexFile = 'site.html';
                        break;
                    case "forms":
                        indexFile = 'forms.html';
                        break;
                }

                console.log("BEFORE REQ URL", req.url);
                req.url = `${indexFile}`;
                console.log("AFTER REQ URL", req.url);
                next();
            });

        },
    }
```

This works on the initial load of the site but I get 404s for everything else.   What should I be doing instead of `req.url`?  I can't use `res.sendFile` because webpack is compiling everything in memory.

Comment: Are you using multiple compiler? https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/tree/master/examples/cli/multi-compiler